# Laravel- Form post going to wrong URL

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am learning Laravel from scratch.

I am doing simple form "POST" but something is missing and I am not able to find out what is missing.

So here is my "routes.php":

`Route::get('cards','CardsController@all');
Route::get('cards/{card}','CardsController@show');
Route::post('cards/{card}/notes','NotesController@new');`

and view:

```
<div>
                <form method="POST" action="cards/{{ $card->id }}/notes">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Note body:</label>
                            <textarea name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

and here is controller:

`

```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  use App\Http\Requests;

   class NotesController extends Controller
   {
       public function new(Request $request){
          return $request->all();
      }
   }
```

`

Now when I submit the form it gives me following error:

`NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`

and the URL in browser becomes:

`http://localhost:88/learning/cards/cards/1/notes`

which is definitely wrong.

I think I am missing something very basic.

Please guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the form action to,

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('cards/'.$card->id.'/notes') }}" >
```

Comment: Yes, it worked but i am following this tutorial
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/9
In which they used the above approach.
Could you please guide why it didnt work

Comment: @user2517610 I used this method. Will get the full url

Comment: Ok, that approach seems more elegant. .. Anyways thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your action starts with "cards/". Change the action to start with '/cards/' so that it's path is not calculated relative to the current route.

```
<form method="POST" action="/cards/{{ $card->id }}/notes">
```